# Updating style attribute dynamically with state React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is a CodeSandox if you want to have a look, code found in component > tabs > Tab.js - [CodeSandox](https://codesandbox.io/s/1wr6nk39yl?fontsize=14)

I have a tabs component that calculates the position of all tabs from the parent class `Tab`. It then positions an element `Tabs-underline` correctly under the tab that is `active` based upon the props provided.

I can style the element fine on load, however, when I hover over a tab, I want the style to adapt to whatever tab is being hovered over. I have this calculated with the `getSizes()` function that updates `this.state.sizes`.

I followed this tutorial, to give you an idea, it just didn't go over how to handle the position of the underline when a user hovers over a tab. 
[YouTube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KlQagQQmwX0)

But I just can't figure out how to update it dynamically with the correct values?

I believe that I should be using state to update the style attribute. Now, I have tried that, however, I keep coming across the issue on initial load that whenever I try to call `getUnderlineStyle()` from anywhere, other than render, `this.state.sizes` is an empty object. And I don't think setting it up in the render function is any use as how am I supposed to manipulate that when I hover??

I'm at a total loss, I've been stuck on this all day for something that seems very simple but no amount of googling has provided me with the solution. I've been thrown into the deep end with React, so this may be a very simple solution.

Below is my component, as I said, works fine on initial load, just not sure how to actually implement hovering to update a state value that then updates a style attribute on `Tabs-underline`

I have left comments to help describe my issue in the code snippet below...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Tabs.scss';

const transitionTime = 200;
const transitionStyle = `left ${transitionTime}ms, right ${transitionTime}ms`;

class Tabs extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         sizes: {},
         // Understand that this is what the style attribute value should be set to but how do I update it, it relies on this.state.sizes to be populated but cannot get it to a stage where it is populated???
         underLineStyle: {},
      };
      this.els = {};
      this.getSizes = this.getSizes.bind(this);
      this.getUnderlineStyle = this.getUnderlineStyle.bind(this);
   }

   componentDidMount() {
   // Is this the correct way to set the state???
      this.setState({
         sizes: this.getSizes()
      });
   }

   componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
      if (prevProps.children !== this.props.children && prevProps.active !== this.props.active) {
         this.setState({
            sizes: this.getSizes()
         });
      }
   }

   getSizes() {
      const rootBounds = this.root.getBoundingClientRect();

      const sizes = {};

      Object.keys(this.els).forEach((key) => {
         const el = this.els[key];
         const bounds = el.getBoundingClientRect();

         const left = bounds.left - rootBounds.left;
         const right = rootBounds.right - bounds.right;

         sizes[key] = { left, right };
      });

      return sizes;
   }

   getUnderlineStyle() {
   // Calling this from within componentDidMount, this.state.sizes is empty?
   // Calling this directly on style attribute works but cannot manipulate on hover???
      if (this.props.active == null || Object.keys(this.state.sizes).length === 0) {
        return({left: '0', right: '100%'});
      }

      const size = this.state.sizes[this.props.active];

      return({
        left: `${size.left}px`,
        right: `${size.right}px`,
        transition: transitionStyle,
      });
   }

render() {

   return (
      <div className="Tabs" ref={el => this.root = el}>
         {React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child, i) => {
            return (
               <div
                  className={(child.key === this.props.active ? 'Tabs-item Tabs-itemActive' : 'Tabs-item') + (i === 0 ? ' Tabs-first' : i === (this.props.children.length - 1) ? ' Tabs-last' : null)}
                  onClick={() => {
                     this.props.onChange(child.key);
                  }}
                  onMouseEnter={/*something needs to go here, but what?*/}
                  ref={el => this.els[child.key] = el}
               >
                  {child}
               </div>
            );
         })}
         {this.props.underline ?
          // style attribute should be set to this.state.underlineStyle, but it currently an empty object?
            <div key={"Tabs-underline"} className="Tabs-underline" style={this.getUnderlineStyle()}></div>
            : null
         }
      </div>
   );
}
}

export default Tabs;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the component's state to be updated based on mouse events, then you'll need to have an event handler, like your "onMouseEnter", that when called, calls this.setState() with the new desired state. It seems like in your case you want to update the underLineStyle state property.

I feel like it would be significantly easier to do this in CSS though, using the :hover selector.

Comment: Thanks, CSS would be easy but these values are dynamic and used across multiple parts of the website of different container widths, the left and right values vary for each different tab, so CSS is not really an option in this case.

Comment: Here is a CodeSandox if you want to have a look, code found in component > tabs > Tab.js - https://codesandbox.io/s/1wr6nk39yl?fontsize=14